# Testing proportion differences on multi sample/multi category data

Tags: multiple-comparisons

My data is like this:
I collected three groups of data randomly collected from three groups: A:(Age < 20), B:(Age 30-50) , C:(Age > 50)

I evaluated the level of people smokes with three categories "Not a smoker", "light smoker", "Heavy smoker".

Now I want to compare if there is a difference in the proportion between these groups. I have only done the basic statistical analysis stuff and I am not sure which Test should I use here? Can I do a T-test of proportions between A and B, and then B and C? Or it should be more complicated than that? And is there any tools for doing this kind of analysis? I have only used "Compared Means" in SPSS so far with numerical variable and I am not sure how to do this kind of analysis with categorical values...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a contingency table for the data.

Then apply [Chi-Square test](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat500/node/56) for the contingency table.